# Accessing elements of a vector in spark

Tags: java, vector, apache-spark

How to access the ith element of the vector in Spark.

The vector is imported from:

```
import org.apache.spark.util.Vector;
```

The code is:

```
JavaRDD<String> block2UsersVector = block2.map( new Function<Vector,String>(){
    public String call(final Vector v){
        return v.element(0).toString();
    }
    });
```

And I am getting error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
return v.element(0).toString();
        ^
symbol: method element(int)
location: variable v of type Vector
```

Is there any predefined method in Vector class?? (Expecting help!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `elements` filed defined on [spark.util.Vector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/core/index.html#org.apache.spark.util.Vector).

Since you're accessing this Scala class from Java, I think you'll have to treat the field access as a method call and add a pair of parentheses:

```
    return v.elements()[0].toString();
```